# How to extract hours/minutes/seconds from np.datetime64

Tags: python, numpy, datetime

I have a datetime object that looks like this:

`t = numpy.datetime64('2020-04-15T13:20:06.810000000')`
From it I want to extract only `13:20:06`. How can I do this?

All answers on SO on similar questions that I have found suggested using `t.hour` or `t.minute`. But when I attempt doing it I get an AttributeError, saying that np.datetime64 object has no such attributes

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Convert it to the pandas Timestamp object:

```
import pandas as pd

t1 = pd.Timestamp(t)
```

and then you may use

```
t1.hour
t1.minute
t1.second
```

(and similar for year, month, day, etc.) to obtain individuals items from it.

Comment: this seems to be the most convenient solution for me. Thanks

Comment: would recommend that method over the conversion to `datetime.datetime` - much simpler.

Answer (score 4):

```
t.astype(str)[11:19]
```

> ```
> '13:20:06'
> ```

---

*The explanation:*

`t.astype(str)` changes your object to the string of the fixed format:

> ```
> '2020-04-15T13:20:06.810000000'
> ```

so you may then select the part of your interest.

Comment: why this if you provide a much more [elegant solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61407267/10197418)?

Comment: @MrFuppes, 'cos I like alternatives. :-) The other reason is that not everyone with installed NumPy has installed pandas, too.

Comment: thanks, i also needed this, for the time part of the datetime64, as a string, so it's more convenient, if a string "13:20:06" is what you want. Btw, one could also call str(t) or t.__str__() directly to get the string, then apply the slicing...

Answer (score 2):

You can do this also just by using the `datetime` from the standard library. It is also about 40% faster than using pandas, or 80% faster than converting to string:

```py
import datetime as dt
import numpy as np 

t = np.datetime64("2020-04-15T13:20:06.810000000")
t1 = dt.datetime.utcfromtimestamp(t.tolist() / 1e9)
```

#### Example output

```py
In [47]: t = np.datetime64("2020-04-15T13:20:06.810000000")

In [48]: t1 = dt.datetime.utcfromtimestamp(t.tolist() / 1e9)

In [49]: t1.hour
Out[49]: 13

In [50]: t1.minute
Out[50]: 20

In [51]: t1.second
Out[51]: 6
```

#### Speed comparison for extracting just hour

```py
In [41]: dt.datetime.utcfromtimestamp(t.tolist() / 1e9).hour
Out[41]: 13

In [42]: pd.Timestamp(t).hour
Out[42]: 13

In [43]: int(t.astype(str)[11:13])
Out[43]: 13

In [44]: %timeit dt.datetime.utcfromtimestamp(t.tolist() / 1e9).hour
760 ns ± 23.2 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000,000 loops each)

In [45]: %timeit pd.Timestamp(t).hour
1.22 µs ± 14 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000,000 loops each)

In [46]: %timeit int(t.astype(str)[11:13])
3.59 µs ± 48.9 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100,000 loops each)
```